# Mongomapper :minimum & :maximum vs. :length

Tags: ruby, activerecord, mongomapper

I try to validate in MongoMapper a string with:

```
key :title,       String, :require => true, :length => 4..30
```

And I got always the error "title is too short (minimum is 4 characters)" also when the string was longer than 4 chars.

If I try it with

```
key :title,       String, :require => true, :minimum => 4, :maximum => 30
```

and it work as excepted. Can someone explain why this happen or why the first thing is wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

MongoMapper uses Activerecord validations.  From their documentation: `validates :password, :length => { :in => 6..20 }`   So you have to use `:in` to denote you are using a range.  See http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_validations_callbacks.html#length

Comment: Okey but what happens when i use the mongomapper function :lenght with a range because in the documentation I only found ":length – Integer, Range, or Hash that is passed to validates_length_of" and my thought was that 4..30 passed to :in

Comment: Yes but you are doing a validation.  This is different than Object#length.  It is using Activerecord validations